# Creating a nested UL from flat array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, nested-lists

This is an array that was built from a JSON file. What I want to do is create a unordered nested list. I have seen a lot of tutorials out there but they usually only work for a simple (id, parent id, name) layout. This array is more complicated than that which is why my attempts don't seem to work.

This is the desired outcome:

- Standard I: Curriculum, Planning, and Assessment

  - Indicator I-A.    Curriculum & Planning

    - I-A-1. Child and Adolescent Development

      - content will go in here
    - I-A-2. Child and Adolescent Development

      - content will go in here
  - More indicators here that are related to Standard I
- Standard II: ....

There are multiple parents, and their IDs are separated by the `*_id` field. I included duplicate fields, with different names, to allow a comparison based off the examples I saw online that could do something like `$parentID == $id`. I was looking into ways of converting this to a tree array to make reading it easier, but ran into similar complications there too.

So to understand the structure below, here is a key:

`[top_id]` = `[standard]`'s ID and is the same as `[top]` for comparison reasons

`[parent_id]` = `[indicators]`'s ID and is the same as `[parent]` for comparison reasons

`[child_id]` = `[element]`'s ID and is the same as `[parent]` for comparison reasons

The others are content associated to the [element] which I can get to show up once I get my list created successfully.

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [top_id] => 1
            [top] => 1
            [parent_id] => 2
            [parent] => 2
            [child_id] => 5
            [child] => 5
            [standard] => Standard I: Curriculum, Planning, and Assessment
            [indicator] => Indicator I-A.   Curriculum & Planning
            [element] => I-A-1. Child and Adolescent Development
            [Connections] => some content here
            [Effective Practice] => some content here
            [Proficient] => some content here
            [Suggested Artifacts] => some content here
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [top_id] => 1
            [top] => 1
            [parent_id] => 2
            [parent] => 2
            [child_id] => 6
            [child] => 6
            [standard] => Standard I: Curriculum, Planning, and Assessment
            [indicator] => Indicator I-A.   Curriculum & Planning
            [element] => I-A-2. Child and Adolescent Development
            [Connections] => some content here
            [Effective Practice] => some content here
            [Proficient] => some content here
            [Suggested Artifacts] => some content here
        )

    )
```

**-- UPDATE WITH ATTEMPT EXAMPLES --**

```
foreach ($nodes as $node => $v) { 

    // id's
    $topID = $v['top_id'];
    $parentID = $v['parent_id'];
    $childID = $v['child_id'];
    $top = $v['top'];
    $parent = $v['parent'];
    $child = $v['child'];;

    // name values
    $standard = $v['standard'];
    $indicator= $v['indicator'];
    $element = $v['element'];
    $connections = $v['Connections'];
    $practice = $v['Effective Practice'];
    $proficient = $v['Proficient'];
    $artifacts = $v['Suggested Artifacts'];

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($standard as $value){
        echo "<li>";
        print $value;
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach($indicator as $v){
            echo "<li>";
            print $v;
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Also

```
    if ($node[$top][] == $topID[]){
        echo "<li>";
        print $standard;
        echo "<ul>";
        if ($node[$parent][] == $parentID[]){
            echo "<li>";
            print $indicator;
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";   
        echo "</li>";
    }
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: Yup just added a couple examples.

Comment: Where do the 'Connections,' 'Effective Practice,' and so on go in your menu? Also -- did you create this data structure or has it come directly from the json? It's rather confusingly laid out!

Comment: @girlwithglasses where it says "content will go in here". That part should be easy for me once I have the lists organized and created.

Comment: @girlwithglasses It's produced from Drupal Views Datasource, which unfortunately only outputs a flat json file - which made all the crazy id's as they are now. I have the ability to edit it more, but I needed to show the relationship somehow and this is what I could rationally come up with at the moment. :( lol

Comment: Are there several 'top' nodes or just the one?

Comment: @girlwithglasses There are 4 Standards in this current setup. Usually about 3 or so Indicators underneath the Standards, and about 4 or so Elements inside of each Indicator. 

I am remaking this tool - http://edevaltools.collaborative.org/demo/teacher/

Comment: Can you paste the json somewhere (e.g. pastebin.com) so I can mess with the data? Thanks for the link!

Comment: @girlwithglasses http://pastebin.com/hGVZWwPR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would gather the data and construct a tree first, and then print the tree out. Some sample code:

```
foreach ($nodes as $item) {
    // gather the data in an assoc array indexed by id
    if ( !isset($data_by_id[ $item['top_id'] ])) {
        $data_by_id[ $item['top_id'] ] = array( 'name' => $item['standard'] );
    }
    if ( !isset($data_by_id[ $item['parent_id'] ])) {
        $data_by_id[ $item['parent_id'] ] = array( 'name' => $item['indicator'] );
    }
    if ( !isset($data_by_id[ $item['child_id'] ])) {
        $data_by_id[ $item['child_id'] ] = array( 
            'name' => $item['element'],
            'contents' => array(
                $item['Connections'],
                $item['Effective Practice'],
                $item['Proficient'],
                $item['Suggested Artifacts'])
        );
    }
    // construct the tree - I've made a simple three tier array
    $tree[ $item['top_id'] ][ $item['parent_id'] ][ $item['child_id'] ]++;
}

// go through the tree and print the info
// this is a recursive function that can be used on arbitrarily deep trees
function print_tree( $data, $arr ){
    echo "<ul>\n";
    // the tree is an associative array where $key is the ID of the node,
    // and $value is either an array of child nodes or an integer.
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "<li>" . $data[$key]['name'] . "</li>\n";
        if (isset($data[$key]['contents']) && is_array($data[$key]['contents'])) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($data[$key]['contents'] as $leaf) {
                echo '<li>' . $leaf . "</li>\n";
            }
            echo "</ul>\n";
        }
        // if $value is an array, it is a set of child nodes--i.e. another tree.
        // we can pass that tree to our print_tree function.
        if (is_array($value)) {
            print_tree($data, $value);
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

print_tree($data_by_id, $tree);
```

You'll need to add in error checking, zapping of strange characters, removal of excess whitespace, etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping thus far @girlwithglasses ! Though I do not get any results from that code. If I add a print_r to test the $tree before the function, I get a multi level array with 1's, though running the function yields no results.

Comment: I'd forgotten to put in a statement to send `$data_by_id` and `$tree` to the tree printing function... try it now. Otherwise, you can write a set of nested loops to go through the tree structure.

Comment: Awesome! This is outputting the list as I would expect, thanks for your help!