# recursion of hierarchy with iterator php

Tags: php, recursion, hierarchy

I'm trying to build an array like the following

```
array([serviceA, children:[abc]], serviceB, serviceC); //no child services from the main array once it becomes a child
```

from the data:

```
$mainAr = [
serviceA
    id: 1
    parent: null
    level: 0
abc
    id: 2
    parent: 1
    level: 1
serviceB
    id: 3
    parent: null
    level: 0
... and so on]
```

My current code calls recurseLevelLoop

```
function recurseLevelLoop($mainAr){
    $newAr = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($mainAr); $i++){
        $parent = $mainAr[$i];
        array_push($newAr, $this->recurseLevel($mainAr, $parent));
    }
    return $newAr;
}
function recurseLevel($mainAr, $parent){
    if($parent['serviceParent'] == null){ // check if there are any child nodes
        return $parent['serviceName'];
    } else {
        // searches all objects if the value of $mainAr['serviceParent'] == $parent['idService']
        $checkChildren = $this->SearchArray($mainAr, 'serviceParent', $parent['idService']); 
        //instantiate $parent['children'] array if none exists
        if(!$parent['children']){$parent['children'] = [];}
        array_push($parent['children'], $this->recurseLevel($mainAr, $mainAr[$checkChildren]));
        //return populated parent service once the children have been resolved
        return array($parent['serviceName'], 'children'=>$parent['children']);
    }
}
```

The problem is the result that comes out is where the child nodes are also in the main Array.

```
array([serviceA, children:[abc]], abc, serviceB, serviceC);
```

I know that I can run a check that will remove all elements with a level > 0 over this array, but my question :

*Is that is there any way to put the iterator in recurseLevel so that I can do away with recurseLevelLoop*

Comment: I'm not clear how you're representing the data structure in the main array... what does `children:[abc]` in `array([serviceA, children:[abc]], abc, serviceB, serviceC);` mean? This item may be useful for processing data to create a hierarchy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433974/creating-a-nested-ul-from-flat-array-in-php/25435286

Comment: ahh thats supposed to be the output. will look, thanks

Comment: edit: just reread, thats the current output of the function, but it should be only be `array([serviceA, children:[abc]], serviceB, serviceC)` where the child service "abc" is only present as a child of serviceA in the array. Apologies for not being clear.